# How can I access to a button inside a customized AlertDialog?

Tags: android, button, onclick, dialog, android-alertdialog

I'm pretty new in Android programming, so I hope this question is easy for you guys.

I'm opening a custom `AlertDialog` with an extra button and a `seekbar` in order to display the progress of playing a song. My problem is that I cannot access to the `onClick` method of that button.

[image: [Customized dialog]

I'm opening the AlertDialog with the following code:

```
public void openAudioPlayer(View view){

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.audio_player_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.audio_player_description)
            .setView(R.layout.dialog_audio_player)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm,null)
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).show();

}
```

Where `dialog_audio_player` is the custom XLM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/playerBox"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/playStateButton"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_player"
            android:onClick="onPlayerClicked"
            android:checked="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playStateButton" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So, I want to control the pushing of that button with my customized `onPlayerCLicked` method, which is included in the same activity that `openAudioPlayer`:

```
public void onPlayerClicked(View view){
    Toast.makeText(this,"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But the program **never** enters there. In fact, the app closes.

How can I do it?

The crash is the following:

```
06-04 12:47:13.587 3928-3928/vmc.songbook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                        Process: vmc.songbook, PID: 3928
                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4698)
                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122)
                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4693)
                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122) 
                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                                                         Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: stop failed.
                                                            at android.media.MediaRecorder.stop(Native Method)
                                                            at vmc.songbook.RecordAudio.stopRecording(RecordAudio.java:121)
                                                            at vmc.songbook.RecordAudio.onToggleClicked(RecordAudio.java:84)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4693) 
                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                                                            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122) 
                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update your method `openAudioPlayer()` as below:**

```
public void openAudioPlayer(View view){

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Custom dialog layout
    View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_audio_player, null);

    // PLAY/PAUSE button
    ToggleButton playStateButton = (ToggleButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.playStateButton);
    playStateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // DO something...
        }
    });

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.audio_player_title)
           .setMessage(R.string.audio_player_description)
           .setView(dialogView)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, null)
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);

    // Create dialog 
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

    // Show dialog
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_audio_player , null);
final AlertDialog alertD = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.playStateButton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

    // btn has been clicked

  }
}); 

 alertD.setView(view);
 alertD.show();
```

Comment: First of all you are not calling create() before calling show() and that's why it's crashing. To use custom view layout see this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not asking how to customize positive and negative buttons, but an extra one in the XLM file...

Comment: @VictorMartinez post your crash log if app stops working.

Comment: @VictorMartinez how did you connect your button with ID in xml?

Comment: I didn't. I don't know how to trigger an action when that button is pressed (android:onClick="onPlayerClicked")

Comment: @VictorMartinez sorry I forgot one line of code now I think it should work.

Comment: Now it works, but only the XLM file is displayed. I want to display also the setTitle, setMessage and Possitive and Negative buttons. How can I do that?

Comment: @VictorMartinez `alertD.setTitle(R.string.audio_player_title).setMessage()` etc.

Comment: I don't know why, but it crashed. Anyway, the solution of FAT, which is very similiar to yours, works :) Thanks to both of you!